# Matlab MCR error running end user application

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I am an end user trying to run a compiled Matlab executable. This executable requires the MCR v80. It seems to use video processing components of the MCR, however the MCR installer did not do any dependency checking. The errors I am getting are quite vague, but I have solved some by installing gstreamer plugins.

My current problem is very vague and I don't know what the problem could be:

```
Warning: No video frames were written to this file. The file may be invalid.
> In VideoWriter.VideoWriter>VideoWriter.close at 289
  In VideoWriter.VideoWriter>VideoWriter.delete at 238
  In evm at 99 
Error using VideoReader/read (line 86)
Unable to read the file.o
```

The app was running on a Ubuntu 13.04 machine alright, and I kept track of the dependencies I installed. Now I'm trying to set it up on Ubuntu 12.04 and am encountering this problem. I'm guessing it is a difference in the dependency tree or something like that, but it is very difficult to track down with only the error message above to go on.

What would be nice is a definitive list of dependencies for MCR v80. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I doubt if this is a dependency issue. It seems like the executable is expecting an input (maybe the name of the video file to written into or the video for processing).

Answer (score 0):

Today I discovered the issue was something to do with running on an EC2 micro instance, where CPU is limited and it is not intended for intense computations. I was trying to see what performance would be like.

Moving to the next size of EC2 machine allowed the app to run. Strangely, there were no messages logged on the system to indicate this is what the problem was.